# Angular 2 - Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: angular

I've used [crunsh](https://github.com/s-a/crunsh-single-page) to minify my Angular2 app ([source code](https://github.com/JozefJarosciak/MortgageCalculatorAngular2)) and it successfully produced app.js, index.html and style.css.

However, when I place those 3 files into a test folder on my domain: http://www.mortgagecalculator123.com/test/ it's not working.

I've inspected the page in Chrome and I am getting a following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined (anonymous function).

Any idea what I am doing wrong? To me it seemed like Angular 2 is somehow not being included in index.html, so I added it it in like this:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
```

But that only creates further errors. It seems I am missing something and I am not sure what.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you are in wrong! angular 2 app use node_modules and very dependency. you can not minify just one script!
if you can minify your code and bundle it , please work with gulp or webpack. 
read this for more details: [Link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Comment: Isn't webpack doing the samething as crunsh here? It goes through everything in Angular 2 package.json and then creates the minified files....